# Pre-generics, cast object from hashmap?

Tags: java, iterator

How do I iterate through a hashmap (containing objects of type Person) and calling methods on the Person object?

I used:

```
for(Iterator it = hashmap.entrySet().iterator(); is.hasNext();){
    Person p = (Person)it.next();
    p.doSomething();
}
```

but when the Person cast is being performed it says the object cannot be cast to a Person object (however it definitely is a subtype of Person).

> java.util.HashMap$Entry cannot be cast to Person.

EDIT this is 1.4!

Comment: You can do a `System.out.println(it.next().getClass())` and find out what is the true type of the object and find out why it fails.

Comment: It says the class type is java.util.HashMap$Entry

Comment: There you go, you're iterating over the Entry objects of your map. Read documentation for `java.util.Map.Entry` to find out how to retrieve the value out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your iterator will be walking through [Map.Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) objects, extract them out as those types first:

```
Person p = (Person)((Map.Entry)it.next()).getValue();
```